# jqGrid with checkbox in all columns

Tags: checkbox, jqgrid

I have a jqGrid with six columns, each with a 'checkbox' format.  I need to get all of the checkboxes' selected and unselected values based on Column Names.  Is it possible?

The first column is to provide an option for selecting all the remaining columns together. 
I'm unable to add event listeners like `onclick` or `onselect` when defining `colModel`.

```js
$("#Grid").jqGrid({
    url: '@Url.Action("Access", "Authorization")' + '?role=' + encodeURIComponent($('input#hIDRole').val()),
    datatype: 'json',
    colNames: ["IDAccess","Permission", "ALL", "Read", "Add", "Edit", "Copy", "Delete"],
    colModel: [
        { name: 'IDAccess', index: 'IDAccess', width: 10, resizable: false, editable: false, hidden: true },
        { name: 'Permission', index: 'Permission', width: 100, resizable: false, editable: false, hidden: false },
        { name: 'ALL', index: 'ALL', editable: true, edittype: 'checkbox', editoptions: { value: "True:False" }, formatter: "checkbox", width: 50, resizable: false, formatoptions: { disabled: false }, onselect: "checkBox(this.value())" },
        { name: 'IsRead_Allowed', index: 'IsRead_Allowed', editable: true, edittype: 'checkbox', formatter: "checkbox", editoptions: { value: "True:False" }, width: 50, resizable: false, formatoptions: { disabled: false }, onclick: "checkBox(checked,this.value)" },
        { name: 'IsCreate_Allowed', index: 'IsCreate_Allowed', editable: true, edittype: 'checkbox', editoptions: { value: "True:False" }, formatter: "checkbox", width: 50, resizable: false, editable: true, formatoptions: { disabled: false }, onclick:"checkBox(event)"  },
        { name: 'IsUpdateAllowed', index: 'IsUpdateAllowed', editable: true, edittype: 'checkbox', editoptions: { value: "True:False" }, formatter: "checkbox", width: 50, resizable: false, editable: true, formatoptions: { disabled: false }, },
        { name: 'IsCopy_Allowed', index: 'IsCopy_Allowed', editable: true, edittype: 'checkbox', editoptions: { value: "True:False" }, formatter: "checkbox", width: 50, resizable: false, editable: true, formatoptions: { disabled: false } },
        { name: 'IsDeleteAllowed', index: 'IsDeleteAllowed', editable: true, edittype: 'checkbox', editoptions: { value: "True:False" }, formatter: "checkbox", width: 50, resizable: false, editable: true, formatoptions: { disabled: false } },
    ],
    //rowNum: 10,
    //rowList: [10],
    pager: "#pager-json",            
    autowidth: true,            
    loadComplete: function () {
        var rowIDs = $("#Grid").jqGrid('getDataIDs');
        for (var i = 0; i < rowIDs.length ; i++) {
            var rowId = rowIDs[i];
            var rowData = jQuery('#Grid').jqGrid('getRowData', rowId);
            //below code to check the All column if the other columns have true in the db. But once checked attribute is added i am not able to uncheck
            if ((rowData['IsRead_Allowed'] == "True") && (rowData['IsCreate_Allowed'] == "True") && (rowData['IsUpdateAllowed'] == "True")
                && (rowData['IsCopy_Allowed'] == "True") && (rowData['IsDeleteAllowed'] == "True")) {
                var check = $("#" + rowId).find('input[type="checkbox"]');
                check.attr('checked', 'checked');
            }
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < rowIDs.length; i++) {
            var rowData = rowIDs[i];
            if (rowData['IsCopy_Allowed'] == null) {
                //alert("1");
                var checkbox = $("#Grid" + rowData.i);
                //checkbox.css("visibility", "hidden");
                checkbox.attr("disabled", true);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: What happens when you try to add an onclick listener?  Does it just not fire when you expect it to, or what?

Comment: it is not firing the listener.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following selector to get all of the input elements:

```
jQuery(".jqgrow td input", "#my_grid").each(function(){
        jQuery(this).unbind('click');
        jQuery(this).click(function(){
            ...
        });
});
```

The `input` element will actually be contained within a `td`:

```
<td ... aria-describedby="my-column"><input type="checkbox" ...></td>
```

You can use the `aria-describedby` attributed on the `td` element to determine whether or not to add your click handler. Something like:

```
var col = jQuery(this).parent().attr('aria-describedby');
if (col === "IDAccess") {
    // Add handler here, etc...
}
```

You would need to go through a similar exercise to find all checkboxes in a particular row, although with the ID you might be able to restrict the search, ie:

```
jQuery(".jqgrow td input", "#" + my_id)
```

---

Alternatively, you can also assign each column a unique class using the [`classes`](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acolmodel_options) colmodel option. For example: `classes:'col1'`. That would simplify your code to setup the click handlers, and may allow you to avoid using the `aria` attribute at all.

Comment: i tried with class for my colmodel and able to get checked property of all my check boxes. Thanks. And now i have one more checkbox column binded with id and when i try to read through grid to get only checked rows, it gives me all id's as checked. i think since a value is binded it takes as checked always. Can any one help in this?